# little kernel 'lk' GPIO toggling

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux, bootloader

while working with thye little kernel for my board which is working with a quactel sc-20 board tried to customize the bootup sequence by toggling the led which is connected to **pin 110**.
I navigated to different folders and got different functions to work with the gpio referring to that inside kernel/main.c I call the required and relevant function to toggle my gpio.

```
gpio_tlmm_config(BOOTLED_STATUS_PIN, 0, GPIO_OUTPUT, GPIO_PULL_UP, GPIO_16MA, GPIO_ENABLE);
```

with help of this very dim light of the led I can see but that looks like due to weak pullup as there is no pull-up register is connected
whereas if I change GPIO_PULL_UP ->to-> GPIO_NO_PULL then led is not turning on.

I tried to use the function which is defined in reg.h file but that also didn't help me out

```
writel(1, (uint32_t *)GPIO_IN_OUT_ADDR(BOOTLED_STATUS_PIN));
```

I am struggling to reach up to the solution please guide me with the suggestion or solution
your suggestion can also help me in constructive way
thanks in advance for the help

Comment: referred to this GitHub link also but didn't get any clue maybe I am missing something
**https://github.com/littlekernel/lk/tree/master**

Comment: i am still clueless with the problem led is not turning up properly after giving setting it with the function inside little kernel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the board I am using, this is the best possible thing I can do after doing long research.
functions are defined as gpio_set and gpio_config but there is no definition available in the bootloader/lk/.